# Lua string.sub() result when end index is less than the initial index

Tags: string, lua, substring

In all the Lua definitions of `string.sub` I could not find what it returns when the end index is positive yet less than than the initial index.

For example, will `string.sub(someString, 3, 2)` always return the empty string `""`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Refer to: [string.sub (s, i [, j])](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.sub):

> If (...) i is greater than j, the function returns the empty string.

`i` and `j` are respectively first and second indices from arguments.

Note that while 5.1's manual [doesn't mention this behaviour](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.sub) (documentation for `string.sub` was extended in 5.2), the implementation didn't change in a meaningful way: [5.1](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lstrlib.c.html#str_sub), [5.2](https://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstrlib.c.html#str_sub), [5.3](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lstrlib.c.html#str_sub) or [5.4](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lstrlib.c.html#str_sub); the behaviour is persistent across those versions.